# No provider for HttpHandler with ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, angular5, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to recreate an authEffect very similar to the [ngrx docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/effects), and getting this error message: 
`Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler!`

the effect service:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpEffects {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private actions$: Actions) {}

  @Effect() login$: Observable<ActionWithPayload> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.SEND_LOGIN),
    mergeMap((action: ActionWithPayload) =>
      this.http.post(SERVER_URL + LOGINAPI.LOGIN, action.payload, config).pipe(
        map(data => ({type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: data})),
        catchError(() => of({type: 'LOGIN_ERROR'}))
      ))
  );
}
```

app.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 10
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([HttpEffects])
  ],
  exports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [ HttpClient ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I've tried to import the effect service in a feature model as well, with `EffectsModule.forFeature()`, but the same error is thrown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in [HttpClient documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http):

> Before you can use the HttpClient, you need to install the
>   HttpClientModule which provides it. This can be done in your
>   application module, and is only necessary once.

So you have to import the *HttpClientModule* instead of *HttpClient*:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
    EffectsModule.forRoot([HttpEffects])
  ],
  exports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```